# Restrict a form assembly field based on value in another field

Tags: form

I have a form with two fields Cost and Price. The cost field is in the section tfa_1 and the price in tfa_2.
I have to restrict the price field such that any value entered in this field will always be less than the value in the cost field.
I tried validations and scripts but nothing is working yet.
Since the values are modified onchange tried this way:

```
document.getElementById('tfa_1').addEventListener('change', validateFields);
    document.getElementById('tfa_2').addEventListener('change', validateFields);
    
    function validateFields() {
      var field1Value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('tfa_1').value);
      var field2Value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('tfa_2').value);
      
      if (field2Value > field1Value) {
        document.getElementById('tfa_2').setCustomValidity('Field 2 value cannot be greater than Field 1 value');
      } else {
        document.getElementById('tfa_2').setCustomValidity('');
      }
    }
```

But no result. Is there any way I can show an error in the Price field if a value is entered in the Price field>Cost field? The error should be shown then and form submission to be prevented.

Thanks....

Comment: You need to check with FormAssembly support.

Comment: @DavidCheng Contacted support. But they don't have an exact workaround